# Raw SQL command not executing using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, rawsql

I have trouble seeding data using the following raw SQL command and entity framework

```
databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
      (@"INSERT INTO    NatureOfBusinessRiskClass
            ( ProductSectionId ,
            NatureOfBusinessId ,
            RiskClassId ,
            ConstructionType ,
            AreaType ,
            SumInsuredLimit ,
            MaximumRate ,
            MinimumRate ,
            IsAggregated ,
            CreatedBy ,
            CreateDate)
      SELECT P.Id,T.NatureOdBusinessId,T.RiskClassId,ConstructionType,AreaType,0.00,
      0,0,0,1,GETDATE() FROM TempNatureBusiness T
            CROSS JOIN TempAreaType A
            CROSS JOIN TempConstructionType C
            CROSS JOIN ProductSection P");
```

When I execute this SQL statement within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studion everything works as expected, but when I use entity framework the tables are not populated and no exception is generated.

Comment: Use SQL Profiler to check if the same query is used and if it executes with other sql users, make sure permission is given

Comment: @user65439 Try this: `Var rowsaffected=databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(....);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was also using RAW sql commands to populate the the tables this query rely on to generate it's content, for example

```
databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO TempAreType...");
databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO TempConstructionType...");
```

Then I executed the command I'm having trouble with,

```
databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
  (@"INSERT INTO    NatureOfBusinessRiskClass
        ( ProductSectionId ,
        NatureOfBusinessId ,
        RiskClassId ,
        ConstructionType ,
        AreaType ,
        SumInsuredLimit ,
        MaximumRate ,
        MinimumRate ,
        IsAggregated ,
        CreatedBy ,
        CreateDate)
  SELECT P.Id,T.NatureOdBusinessId,T.RiskClassId,ConstructionType,AreaType,0.00,
  0,0,0,1,GETDATE() FROM TempNatureBusiness T
        CROSS JOIN TempAreaType A
        CROSS JOIN TempConstructionType C
        CROSS JOIN ProductSection P");
```

At the end I executed

```
databaseContext.SaveChanges();
```

Obviously this statemnent will commit my database changes, so the `TempAreaType` and `TempConstructionType` tables did not have any data when executing the third command. When I executed the commadn in Microsoft SQL Server Management studio, my changes were already commited to the database and the command worked.

The solution was to call the

```
databaseContext.SaveChanges();
```

after the first to commands and then again at the end, for example

```
databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO TempAreType...");
databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO TempConstructionType...");

databaseContext.SaveChanges();

databaseContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand
  (@"INSERT INTO    NatureOfBusinessRiskClass
        ( ProductSectionId ,
        NatureOfBusinessId ,
        RiskClassId ,
        ConstructionType ,
        AreaType ,
        SumInsuredLimit ,
        MaximumRate ,
        MinimumRate ,
        IsAggregated ,
        CreatedBy ,
        CreateDate)
  SELECT P.Id,T.NatureOdBusinessId,T.RiskClassId,ConstructionType,AreaType,0.00,
  0,0,0,1,GETDATE() FROM TempNatureBusiness T
        CROSS JOIN TempAreaType A
        CROSS JOIN TempConstructionType C
        CROSS JOIN ProductSection P");

databaseContext.SaveChanges();
```